# What shebang for Anaconda Python on my directory of Server

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, python

I have anaconda python distribution in `~/anaconda/bin/python` but what shebang can I use to call this version of python instead of the old one that is default on the server?

`# /opt/python/bin/python2.7` is the one i've been trying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rest of the first line after the shebang is parsed as an interpreter directive.

If you want your script to be interpreted / run by an specific binary you need to point to that binary after the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

In this case you need to write something like this:

`#!/home/yourusername/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the shebang text environment name agnostic?

Comment: What do you mean by environment in this context? You could overwrite the `path` on the os level but that might break os python packages and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the already accepted answer (and reply to 0xc0de's comment), I think we can use:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then we need to activate the `Conda` environment, or source the custom Python path that we want to use.

By doing so, `#!/usr/bin/env` will find the right Python version, and also will make sure that the script will run correctly inside the virtual environment.